# Duplicate content between multi-sites

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I'm working on a feature of a Drupal 8 multisite with separated databases for each site trying to implement the following requisite.

When posting news to the main site (all the other sites are subdomains) the user has to have the option to choose other sites where he wants the same news to be available.

I"m starting doing this with a module and hooks, BTW I never worked with Drupal before, and I'm guessing if there is an existing module that could do that.

Would someone recommend a module I could try?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

On the publishing end, you'd need to categorize the data by site (e.g. use term references). Then expose that data as JSON using the built-in Views module. Allow that view to filter by site, to allow the subsites to select the content it wants to import.

On the consuming end:

- There used to be the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module that allowed a Drupal site to fetch data from a source and load that data onto content types on the site. But that module is still in development.
- Alternatively, you could build a [migration](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview) that is triggered in a [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.2.x). Migrate is already in core, I recommend also installing [Migrate Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) and [Migrate Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) for additional utilities.

In both cases, they would hit the main site at the url that Views is exposing, filter by the site term they want, and consume the JSON it returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll be trying it!

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a new approach using [Deploy - Content Staging](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module which allows, in collaboration with Multiversion, Replication, and RELAXed Web Services modules to share content between different Drupal 8 sites.

You can find very good documentation on how to use Deploy module for sharing content on multisite [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/deploy/drupal-to-drupal-deployment-between-two-or-more-sites)
Also, you can visit the official module website from [here](https://www.drupaldeploy.org)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll be trying it!

Comment: Beware the Multiversion module.

Comment: @Kevin would you elaborate?

Comment: Once you have it, you cannot get rid of it.