# Can entity IDs (node, taxonomy, etc.) be synchronized across environments?

Tags: views, 8, deployment

It seems the [content synchronization](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync) module syncs entities UUIDs, but not their entity IDs (like TID, NID, etc). Since it only does UUID, this can result in environments with mismatched IDs for the same entity.

Views filters based on entities filter based on the entity ID and not the UUID.

If your deployment target ends up having different TID than your view is filtered on, it will result in it being broken or showing wrong results.

I assume we can't be the only organization using the combination of the core config sync and the [content synchronization](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync) module and so I'm curious how others are dealing with this issue.

Right now we're considering just copying the database over or maybe writing a script to update the IDs in the DB.

Comment: I don't use that contrib module. I first play around in dev with dummy data, if necessary, to determine how I'll set it up. Then I add the real data to live as unpublished and pull down to dev.

Comment: I usually use Deploy - Content staging for this. I answered a similar question here: [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284491/duplicate-content-between-multi-sites/284542]

Comment: I had considered Deploy, but I was put off by it being beta and not updated since 2019 and it was failing tests.